# Were Joseph and Mary husband and wife before Christ was born?

Tags: marriage, joseph, mary

Specifically I am wondering what can be gathered from the Greek in Matthew 1:16-25.  I've seen a similar discussion [here on Luke 2:5](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/31647/is-there-any-ambiguity-in-luke-25-to-whether-mary-and-joseph-were-already-marri) In Matthew, there are more verses which seem to mention "husband" and "wife" and "taking" and saying that they are "espoused" or "betrothed" or "engaged" depending upon translation.  There is also the statement that Joseph was considering "putting away" (or divorcing) Mary.

"Espoused" I would understand to mean "having a spouse" but "engaged" would be more like a date having been set to become spouses later.  While they haven't consummated the marriage as it was "before they came together," were they already husband and wife?  I am hoping for some Greek translation expertise.

Comment: _When as his mother Mary was **espoused** to Joseph, **before they came together**, she was found with child of the Holy Ghost._ Matthew 1:18.

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks for the suggestion.  I edited the question to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding this issue does not lie in the Greek, but in the Jewish custom of espousal. A betrothal in Jewish tradition involved a legally binding marriage contract, requiring a [certificate of divorce](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6643-get) to dissolve.

> The term ["betrothal"](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5843-erusin) in Jewish law must not be understood in its
> modern sense; that is, the agreement of a man and a woman to marry, by which the parties are not, however, definitely bound, but which may be broken or dissolved without formal divorce. Betrothal or engagement such as this is not known either to the Bible or to the Talmud.

The marriage had been contracted, but not consummated. Unlike in modern societies, it could not be annulled so Joseph had planned to "quietly put her away," prior to the interventional of the angel who informed him that the child was not conceived in adultery.